# Trouble with generating custom javadoc; 'cannot find doclet'

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I'm having a go at creating a custom Javadoc generator using `Doclet`, but I'm running into some issues.

I'm following [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) and initially had trouble with including the `tools.jar` file in my project, but I managed to fix this.

My issue now is that after running this command...

```
javadoc -doclet ListClass -docletpath .  MyClass.java
```

...I am getting the message...

> javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class ListClass

As I said, I've mostly been following the tutorials from the official documentation, but here is my code for reference.

**`ListClass.java`**:

```
import com.sun.javadoc.*;

public class ListClass {

    public static boolean start(RootDoc root) {
        ClassDoc[] classes = root.classes();
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(classes[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

And **`MyClass.java`**:

```
/**
 * Documentation for my class
 */
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    /**
     * Documentation for my static void method
     *
     * @param param This is the parameter it takes in
     */
    public static void myStaticVoidMethod(String param) {

    }

}
```

So what I am asking is why I am getting the error I posted above. If someone was able to provide a more comprehensive guide of how `Doclet` works that would be great as well.

---

Note: I'm using IntelliJ IDE for my project. Here is my directory structure:

- .idea

  - ...
- out

  - ...
- src

  - ListClass.java
  - MyClass.java
- JavadocGenerator.iml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your ListClass file. Something like:

```
javac -d . ListClass.java -cp /path/to/tools.jar
```

Doclet classes are part of the tools jar, so you'll need to include it as your compile-time dependency.

Then your command

```
javadoc -doclet ListClass -docletpath .  MyClass.java
```

should work.

**edit**

For you project structure, if you're compiling from the root directory, make sure to reference your files through their subdirectories, and make sure any absolute windows paths are double-quoted:

```
javac -d . ./src/ListClass.java -cp "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/lib/tools.jar"
```

This would create a compiled ListClass file at the root of the project, and from there use your javadoc command:

```
javadoc -doclet ListClass -docletpath .  ./src/MyClass.java
```

It would be better to create a classes directory to place your compiled classes, as opposed to in the root of the project, but I'm just working with the structure you've provided. See the documentation for [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Running `javac -d . ListClass.java -cp C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/lib/tools.jar` gives me `javac: file not found: ListClass.java`, so I changed it to `... src/ListClass.java ...` (see my updated question with the directory hierarchy). Now running this new command (with the `src/`) gives me the error `javac: invalid flag: Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/lib/tools.jar`.

Comment: You are pretty close with what you have. I think you just need to put the path in quotes, and make sure you're executing javac and javadoc from the correct directories.. see my update.

Comment: running the javac I get this `warning: com\sun\javadoc\RootDoc.class(com\sun\javadoc:RootDoc.class): major ver
sion 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.` any idea about that ?

Comment: command line work, but how can we do these things in IntelliJ IDE? I can't find any option to compile my doclet in the Generate JavaDoc dialog.